# Unresolved compilation problem: scanner cannot be resolved. How do I solve this problem?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

When running this code;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Bank of America");
        System.out.println("Input your name;");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello there "+name);
    }
}
```

I receive the following error message;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    scanner cannot be resolved

    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

I've already searched online for solutions, and none of them work for me. Most of them show examples where a ´;´ is missing, or it wasn't imported, or that the JDK was out of date. I've already imported java.util.Scanner, my JDK and version of Eclipse are up to date, I mean I installed them all 5 hours ago, I don't understand what the problem is or how to begin resolving it. I'm working with the Eclipse IDE 2023-03 and jdk-20.

Comment: Java is case sensitive, so `scanner cannot be resolved` is telling you about a symbol named `scanner` rather than a symbol named `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Scanner` reference is named `input` (not `scanner`). Change

```
String name = scanner.nextLine();
```

to

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

**Or**, change

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: That worked splendidly, thanks! Now I feel embarrassed over such a simple solution, I guess the YouTube Tutorial I'm following is out dated. Thanks a ton for the help!